# How to say that someone views others through stereotypes?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, prepositions

Alan thinks all Chinese people are bad drivers.

How to complete the following sentence about Alan.

> Alan ------ to/toward/about Chinese people.

Is stereotypical, has stereotype, look stereotypically, or ?
Also about the preposition: to, toward, about, or ... ?

As far as I could research, none of the above suggestion are highly popular on the web. "to have stereotypical attitude" are used too, but I don't know if it is good. I want to know the most idiomatic way to say such a sentence using "stereotype" or related words.

Comment: Please include the research you've done

Comment: *is prejudiced*, *is biased*, or, if you drop the preposition, *stereotypes* (as a verb).

Comment: How about "human"?

Comment: @HotLicks "human" for what?

Comment: @Clare done . >>

Comment: Alan is prejudiced against ___ / Alan is biased against ___ / Alan stereotypes ___

Comment: @Sasan - "Human" for someone with prejudices/stereotypes.

Comment: @HotLicks Haha. You mean as in "human for someone with tendency to abuse others and colonize them"?

Comment: @Sasan - I mean that all people have these tendencies.

Answer (score 2):

> Alan *stereotypes* Chinese people. (without preposition)

This may not be particularly elegant, but meets your query.

Comment: Great! Is the verb form of stereotype common ??

Comment: @Sasan The reason I say it may not be elegant is that it seems a bit sterile. "holding a stereotype about" may flow better in a sentence: "Despite his  extensive travels in Asia, Alan holds stereotypes about the Chinese." The verb form would work here too, but as you suggest, it may be less common.

Comment: @Sven Now that you have used it, I am sure I have heard it being spoken in the UK. I've Googled it and it's there.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

> Alan is prejudiced against Chinese people.

or

> Alan is bigoted towards Chinese people.

These aren't specific to stereotyping, but they get the point across that Alan has some sort of prejudicial attitude about Chinese people. Another option that uses the word "stereotype" is

> Alan harbors a stereotype about Chinese people.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word 'blinkered' which I think is suitable.

> A blinkered person is unable or unwilling to understand other people's beliefs, and blinkered opinions or ways of behaving show someone is unable or unwilling to understand other people:

[Blinkered](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blinkered)

Answer (score 1):

[Jaundiced Eye](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+jaundiced+eye) : You might choose to say - " *Alan views Chinese people with a jaundiced eye*". In this case it means, Alan, has a biased view towards Chinese people.